# Discord bot cannot get users collection by ID

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I must be missing something because I am fairly sure this should work, since I have used this same method before in a different command in the same bot...

I have a bot that connects to a mysql database. Inside a table in the database that stores the info for a match of a game I'm making, I store the Discord ID's of each player. After pulling those ID's from the table, specifying which one I'd like the user object retrieved for, and trying to use `.get()` (also attempted to use `.find()` with a username instead), both result in "undefined"... I have a feeling the bot doesn't find the entire user collection, because when I `console.log(client.users)`, I get `Collection [Map] {}` So, it looks to be empty? I have also put in the ID itself instead of a variable and it still can't find it. So, I have a feeling the bot just doesn't get the users collection for some reason.

In the below code:

playerIDArray = the player ID's I stored at the start of the match of the game, pulling them from the mysql table. Stored in array format ("player 1's ID" as index 0, "player 2's ID" as index 1, "player 3's ID" as index 2, etc)

playerIndex = the index of the target player in playerIDArray, found in an earlier step before the below code runs, that I know returns what I expect.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
...
...
var targetUserID = playerIDArray[playerIndex]
var targetUser = client.users.get(targetUserID)
console.log(targetUser)
```

Each time I run this, I get "undefined" and for the life of me can't figure out why... I just want to retrieve the user group so I can send a message to that user, giving them an opportunity to counter before I modify the mysql table and move cards around that would then need to be immediately altered again to restore what was just removed via a counter card.

I must just be dumb and am missing something but I'm lost as to what to try now... Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `client.users` ( and other discord.js Collections ) after the `ready` event fired.

So you need to put the code that uses `client.users` into
`client.on('ready', () => { /* CODE */});`

`ready` will be fired after successful `client.login('token');`.

Comment: I am using a command handler, so I assumed the index.js file runs first. I know the "bo is ready" message that is console logged appeared before this command is even input. Not sure how that affects things though.

Comment: I put `console.log(client.users)` inside the index.js file in the `client.on('ready')` and it does indeed show the user objects, but it doesn't work in the command still. It comes up as "undefined" like it did before. I mean, all I did was log client.users so that is expected, but it doesn't help my issue at all.